# How to test for operating system in ant build

Tags: ant, build

It seems the only reliably provided property by ant is the "os.name" property.  However this name has variants ;lie "Windows 8" "Windows 7" etc

But for my purposes both are "Windows" -

Is there a way to conditionally set a property based on a partial string match of another property value like the pseudo code below? specifically the os.name as the source value? using the default task set provided with a generic ant install?

```
if(a.property 'contains' "Windows")
    another.property = "windows value"
else if(a.property contains 'Linux')
    another.property = "linux value"
endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `os family`

```
        <condition property="another.property" value="windows value" >
            <os family="windows"  />
        </condition>


        <condition property="another.property"  value="linux value" >
            <os family="unix"  name="Linux"/>
        </condition>
```

Comment: I also noticed the else="value if not true" in this "condition" node.
Now looks like what I really want is to do conditionally define a "macrodef" one version for windows and one for linux so all the tasks expanding the macro adapt - another question :)

Comment: You may use else if windows and Linux are the only targeted OS and you don't deploy on AIX or something

Comment: Oleg Pavliv - yes the nature of that logic a more complex situation would be more like a "switch" constructed out of these elements.  But frankly what this is to do is immediately get out of ant because it is really NOT programmable and spawn a ruby/rake based script which has to be spawned differently in the windows backslash environment using "cmd" vs any of the unix variants. :) :)

Comment: Programming in ant has it's own little peculiarities. As every other programming language. You may accept them or switch to something else. Now grunt is becoming a trend